# Cosa vuol dire "e vada per"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La goccia che scava*, di Francesco Luti, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Durante il viaggio, a parte qualche apprezzamento sulla ventenne  Bosé di *Cronaca d'un amore*, ci fu un po' di maretta per opinioni divergenti riguardo a *Ladri di biciclette*, benché tutti concordi nello stimarlo capolavoro. Qualcuno sostenne che Ricci, nella sua veste di attacchino, mal rappresentava l'operaio tipico. **E vada per** il problema della disoccupazione ben raffigurato, ma dov'erano nel film le grandi organizzazioni politiche e sindacali?

La mia domanda è sull'espressione "e vada per" che appare nel testo. L'ho trovata alla [voce "andare" del dizionario Garzanti](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=andare%201):

> **e vada, per questa volta!**, e sia, passi

Non sono sicura, però, che questo sia il significato nel contesto del testo e, a dire il vero, non capisco del tutto bene la spiegazione del Garzanti. Dunque, mi potreste spiegare cosa significa "e vada per" nel contesto del passaggio sopra citato?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La locuzione *vada per* viene usata per esprimere una concessione, come anche riportato dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/andare1/):

> *vada!*, passi, lasciamo correre: *per questa volta vada, ma un’altra
>   volta guai a te!*;

Nel passaggio riportato significa in pratica:

> **E ammettiamo pure che** il problema della disoccupazione *[sia stato]* ben raffigurato *[nel film Ladri di Biciclette]*...

Comment: E, quindi, secondo il Treccani, si potrebbe anche dire "E passi per il problema della disoccupazione ben raffigurato, ..."?

Comment: @Charo secondo me sì, sarebbe corretto.